# Multiple languages in web service

Tags: php, ios, web-services

Currently I'm using a php web service to retrieve the information from MySQL.
I'm dealing with multiple languages including chinese/japanese/french characters, I'm having issues displaying chinese/japanese and a few other languages.

```
<?php

    echo "你好";

?>
```

For example, when I'm trying to echo simple chinese characters, what shows is "ä½ å¥½" instead, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: Set your character encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably set the character encoding.

This is traditionally done by setting the html content-type header. The default is usually:

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`

You can change this via php by using the [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Some other resources for you:

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure the file is saved as UTF-8 (without BOM)

2) Tell the browser that it's UTF-8 (as hafichuk explained)

3) Make sure the browser is using a font that has Chinese/Japanese/etc characters (a ton of fonts do not have them -- if you've done 1 and 2, this could very well be the problem)